# Failed to restart varnish.service: Unit not found

Tags: varnish

```
[root@server21 ~]# service varnish restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart varnish.service
Failed to restart varnish.service: Unit not found.
```

This worked like 3 days ago, but today it stopped working. It works on other servers, but on this one it doesn't work.

I did df -h and I still have 600 gb left, so I am wondering what might have caused this.

Comment: What have you done so far to try to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Run `ls -ltrah /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d` and check if the the file is there, if so `cat` the file and track down the binaries.